# Eclipse error on Mac <iostream>

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, macos, path

Eclipse will not allow me to include iostream, it says unresolved inclusion. I'm on a mac 10.8.2, and have also downloaded Xcode. i read something about going to preferences and adding a new path, but it just hasnt worked. please help!

unresolved inclusion: iostream
Program gcc not found on PATH
Program g++ not found on PATH

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Always show your code and the error message, we can't guess !